# Find closest select box with a class from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the starting point of an element that happens to be a select box (element has a class of: `service_category_selection`) I want to find another select box (element has a class of: `service_selection`).

I need to grab specifically the closest element with class: `service_selection` because I don't want to grab all of the elements with that class.

Snapshot of how far away that first select box is from the second select box:

[image: find closest element]

Assume that `$(this)` already contains the first select box.  Now I just need to draw the route to the closest next select box with the class: `service_selection`.

I attempted to use `.closest` but it wasn't working for me.

Example:  `var el = $(this).closest(".service_selection");`

Comment: Is there a parent container that wraps those 3 `divs`?

Comment: @tymeJV yes, I will update the image.

Comment: The jQuery function `.closest()` is for finding the closest parent matching the selector given.  How are you defining closest?  The dom is a tree - two grandchildren could be considered "close" based on generation, based on common grandparents, based on whether they are siblings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the overall top parent container - then `find` the element:

```
var el = $(this).closest(".row").find(".service_selection");
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing this kind of navigation is a bit hackish and easy to break since your logic highly rely on your layout. I suggest you to use a unique CSS class on that element and access it directly.

Comment: Are you suggesting to add an id to the row?  If so, unfortunately that would not work in my situation because each row is dynamically added, and each row should have the same functionality so a class is more appropriate than an id.

Comment: didn't know about the rows that were dynamically added, but still be carefull with dom navigation, simple changes in the layout can leads to bugs very quickly, a simple solution to avoid that is by relying on agnostic classes. By having `<div class="row item_row">` and relying on your specific class in your javascript.